# Can we make MULTIPLE COPY/MOVE (in parallel) to same target disk?

Tags: windows, partitioning, filesystems, file-transfer, data-transfer

It is a good practice (either recommended or not recommended) to do multiple (in-parallel) file transfers to same target?

[image]

I mostly care about backups - i.e. I create `C` & `D` disk backups **in parallel** to external HD, and how filesystem handles when two concurrent operations try to write the data on the same sector?
is there any theoretical glitch that might happen in such cases? (i.e. even if any single byte of first transferring might be overwriten by the second transfer?)

(BTW, I don't mind about speed performance at this point)

Comment: If you are writing to HDD it is **much** slower to do it concurrently rather than consecutively as disk arm has to move back and forth.

Comment: *"how filesystem handles when two concurrent operations try to write the data on the same sector?"* -- That is impossible, especially during file copying, i.e. each copy of each file occupies its own sectors.  There can never be overlap (except for SUNOS fragment sharing). Otherwise there are rules/procedures to avoid simultaneous writes long before the HDD is involved.  E.G.  typically a program will open a file for exclusive write access, so all other programs are denied write capability to that file by the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually wrote a huge reply to this, and then decided it's better just to keep my answer simple:

No, you will not see any significant performance gains copying files to the same disk in parallel... but might actually see minor loss in performance if you have many copy jobs going on at the same time.

This is especially true for spindle-drives (with a physical read-head that has to move around)... but not exclusive to them.  Even though solid-state disks (USB flash drives, SSDs, SD cards) have no moving parts, the OS still writes to them in a "serial" manner.  Instead of writing two files in parallel, it simply flip-flops between the multiple write-operations, as the files are copied.  This causes a bit of "overhead" which causes delays.

If you really want to increase performance, try copying files to a disk that is NOT your primary OS disk.  While you are copying, the OS is also trying to get some work done.  (i.e. Memory Paging, loading programs, writing logs, etc...)

Comment: *"This is especially true for spindle-drives (with a physical read-head that has to move around)"* -- That's poorly worded.  FYI there are (and I've used them) fixed-head disk drives that have rotating platter and a spindle motor.  The heads do not move. because there is a R/W head assembly per track.  The accurate phrase you could use would be "moving-head disk drive".

Comment: @sawdust, I appreciate your comments, but I can honestly say that you have NOT ever used a fixed-head disk on windows 10.  Since the OP was asking specifically about Windows 10, that's a moot point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I missed whole point (added to question). I was not concerned about SPEED/PERFORMACE actually, I was concerned about if there might be any theorical glitch so one file locked/overwrote another file's bytes.

Comment: If you're copying files with the same file-names... you might end up with "overwrite x file?" prompts... and not be fully sure which copy process is the one that had previously written the file... but other than that, no, it won't merge or corrupt files.